# Relative jump out of range by

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I get the message **"(76)Relative jump out of range by 000Eh bytes"** and **(79)Relative jump out of range by 0007h bytes"** whenever I input CMP octal, '3'. I'm supposed to do up until the 7th octal number but it always gives me an error when I try to do the 3rd octal number. I can only do 0,1, and 2 until it gives me an error. I don't know what I'm supposed to do. I've tried everything that I can as far as I've been taught but I still can't get any results. Please help me. I'm new to assembly. **P.S. I'm using DOSBox 0.74**

```
.Model small

.data
txt1 db "Octal to Binary Converter$"
txt2 db "Enter an Octal Symbol: $"
title0 db "000$"
title1 db "001$"
title2 db "010$"
title3 db "011$"
title4 db "100$"
title5 db "101$"
title6 db "110$"
title7 db "111$"

mess db "Press ESC to exit...$"
invalid db "Input is invalid. Try again.$"
keypress db ?
octal db ?

.code
Start:
Mov AX, @data
Mov ds, ax

sys_st:
Mov AH, 6
Mov AL, 0
Mov BH, 15
Mov ch, 0
Mov cl, 0
Mov DH, 100
Mov DL , 100
Int 10H

Mov AH, 2
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 5
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, txt1 
Int 21H

JMP sys_st2

sys_st2:
Mov AH, 2
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 8
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, txt2 
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 1
Int 21H
Mov octal, AL 

CMP octal, '0'
JE sys_0

CMP octal, '1'
JE sys_1

CMP octal, '2'
JE sys_2

CMP octal, '3'
JE sys_3


CMP octal, '0'
JNE sys_invalid

CMP octal, '1'
JNE sys_invalid

CMP octal, '2'
JNE sys_invalid

CMP octal, '3'
JNE sys_invalid

sys_0:
Mov AH, 2
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 11
Mov DH, 11 
Int 10H

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, title0 
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 15 
Int 10H 

JMP sys_exit

sys_1:
Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 11
Mov DH, 11 
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, title1
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 15 
Int 10H 

JMP sys_exit

sys_2:
Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 11
Mov DH, 11 
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, title2
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 15 
Int 10H 

JMP sys_exit

sys_3:
Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 11
Mov DH, 11 
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, title3
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 15 
Int 10H 

JMP sys_exit

sys_invalid: 
Mov AH, 2 
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5 
Mov DH, 11 
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, invalid 
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 1 
Int 21H 
JMP sys_st 

sys_exit: 

Mov AH, 2
Mov BH, 0
Mov DL, 5
Mov DH, 14
Int 10H 

Mov AH, 9
Lea DX, mess 
Int 21H 

Mov AH, 1 
Int 21H 
Mov keypress, AL 

CMP keypress, 27
JNE sys_exit 

JMP exit 

Exit: 
Mov AH, 4ch 
Int 21H 
End Start
```

Comment: Relative jumps can only jump forward 127 bytes or -128 in 16-bit code. You could branch to a label that then jumps to the label you are getting to.Alternatively you'd have to find a way to restructure your code so that the relative jump is closer to the label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tasm : Relative jump out of range by 0020h bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751025/tasm-relative-jump-out-of-range-by-0020h-bytes)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Not true. The longer relative jumps are also available but you need to explicitly request 80386 opcodes to be enabled.

Comment: @FUZxxl : Although not tagged as such, I assumed from the code produced that he was generating purely 16-bit code. I am well aware of `.386` (and related) directive to support 32-bit instructions. But the provided code is 16-bit DOS, and I assumed that the OP may want to stick with 16-bit. I wasn't going to muddy the waters.

Comment: @MichaelPetch These are not 32-bit instructions, they don't have a 66h or 67h prefix. The long relative jumps of course work in 16 bit mode just fine, it's just that they have been introduced by the 80386. Just because your code runs in 16 bit mode doesn't mean you have to restrict yourself to opcodes introduced with the 8086.

Comment: Yes, and I assumed that we are sticking with 16-bit code. If the OP wanted 386 based instructions he would have had a .386 directive. I am not converting this into a different connection. I mean tthey were made available on 386 processors, but that makes an assumption that s what the OP wants. I am going strictly on the fact that there is no `.386` directive, and that it was intentional. DOSBox will support it but I don't know if he intends to run on real 8086/80286 hardware.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You said “32 bit instruction” which a longer relative jump (e.g. opcode `0f 85`) isn't. Thus my answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl : I addressed that faux pas when I said this in my last comment _I mean tthey were made available on 386 processors,_  .

Comment: Or you can simplify and shorten your code, to fit into +-rel8 range. There's so much duplicity in your code ... (but I'm not going to post modified version, as you don't use NASM for compiling, and the MASM/TASM syntax is now annoying to me, with those illogical things like `mov octal,al`)

Answer (score 9):

Add a `.386` directive to your file to be able to use relative jump instructions with larger offsets introduced with the 80386. Alternatively, find the offending jump and replace it with something like this:

```
   jnz foo ; this jump is too long
```

replace with

```
   jz bar ; opposite conditional
   jmp foo ; unconditional jumps can have larger offsets
bar:
   ...
```

Comment: This first part assumes the OP intends to always target real hardware or an  emulator that has 386 emulation turned on (It happens to be DOSBox does by default). It won't work on a 16-bit processor 286/8086/186 etc. That's just an assumption on your part. As for the second part that is already better answered in the duplicate question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Dosbox does emulate 80386 opcodes. See [here](http://www.dosbox.com/information.php).

Comment: I brought that up in my comment. You probably didn't see it right away since I edited it in a couple seconds after the original. I also expanded it to mention real hardware.