# Dosbox error A2053: Jump out of range 60 bytes

Tags: dosbox

[It says that Jump out of range by 60 bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg5nW.png)

To solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative jump out of range by 0020h bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751025/relative-jump-out-of-range-by-0020h-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Conditional jumps in 8086 Assembly (and most assembly languages) have a limited distance they can jump. In other words, there's too much code between your jump instruction and the destination (in this case, 60 bytes too many). You didn't post your code so I can't tell you exactly what line to fix, but in general the solution is straightforward.

```
cmp ax,bx
jnz goHere
    ; more code is here than the conditional jump will allow
goHere:
; finish up what we were doing
ret
```

In order to fix the above code, we have to reverse the condition and `JMP`, since `JMP` isn't as limited as `Jxx` is.

```
cmp ax,bx
jz continue:
   jmp goHere
continue:
; finish up what we were doing
ret
goHere:
; now we can get here even though we have too much code for a conditional jump
jmp continue  ;this will also have enough range to go there.
```

There's several ways to re-arrange your code to allow conditional jumps to work as intended, and still get the desired outcome. This is just one technique for it.