i get this error trying to jump to the end point
this the procedure for the esc press to exit
i am trying to jump from this proc to the exit to stop game whenever esc is pressed. but it says that escpressed is out of range
proc escpressed
mov ah,1h
int 16h
cmp al,27
je endgame
ret
endp escpressed
(endgame: is located right before the exit)
i get this error
apple1.ASM(86) Relative jump out of range by 021Ah bytes
i think theres a line that should make long jumps possible but i am not sure
i tried putting some code from chat gpt but it didnt work

If my answers (3 by now) help you out, then please consider clicking the accept checkmark on the left side.

Based on the exact error message I assume you are using TASM. And if that is the case this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751025/relative-jump-out-of-range-by-0020h-bytes . An easy fix is to add JUMPS to the beginning of the ASM file. The assembler will then generate code to reach beyond the regular limits.

In your very first question I see that you used P186. Maybe use P386 to get access to long near conditional jumps? The ability was added with the arrival of the 80386 architecture.
And if that doesn't work, there's always the simple workaround:
proc escpressed
  mov  ah, 01h   ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h       ; -> AX ZF
  jz   notESC    ; (*)
  cmp  al, 27
  jne  notESC
  jmp  endgame
notESC:
  ret
endp escpressed

(*) Please don't interpret AX (or AL or AH) without first inspecting the Zero Flag.
